# In vimrc, what's difference between "syntax on" and "syntax enable"?

Tags: vim, syntax

Seems both options are provided to make programming language highlighting effective. But what's the difference between these 2 options, can I just use on of them? Are they exclusive of each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:help :syntax-on`:

> The `:syntax enable` command will keep your current color settings.  This
>   allows using `:highlight` commands to set your preferred colors before or
>   after using this command.  If you want Vim to overrule your settings with the defaults, use:
>
> ```
> :syntax on
> ```